# How to implement NestedTabBar Controller in ios?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I need to implement a Nested TabBar application. For example, There will be four tabbar items on the top, when i click on any tab bar item, it has to load tabbarcontroller which will contain 3 tabbar items at the bottom, like wise each top tab bar item will launch a tabbarcontroller. 
I tried with MHTabbarcontroller adding it three tab bar controllers to it, but its not working.
 i need to achieve some thing like this. 
below is my code to add three tab bar controllers into MHTabBarcontroller.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
TabBarViewControllerOne *TbOne = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabVcOne"];
TabBarViewControllerTwo *TbTwo = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabVcTwo"];
TabBarViewControllerThree *TbThree = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabVcThree"];
 NSArray *viewControllers = @[TbOne, TbTwo,TbThree];
MHTabBarController *tabBarController = [[MHTabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate = self;
tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Anyway, I got the answer, i was able to customize the MHTabbarcontroller to have nested tabs.i think it is best Custom tab bar controller till now.